# jQuery: Fetch data on a part of page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have seen some websites load static data on a page first, and in some part of it the dynamic data is loaded with jquery. For example please see this image:

[image]

At the moment, I fetch data from db using a simple mysql query, eg. `select * from my_photos.`
I don't know how to do this with jQuery and PHP, so I'd be thankful if you can give me some example.

Comment: so what is the question actually, or did i miss something...

Comment: What is the question if you know how to do it? Why would you need an example then? There are plenty jquery/ajax sample out there.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I meant I don't know how to do it with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) like this:

```
$('#div').load('sections.php #section1');
```

The #section1 part will filter out sections.php and only bring back the #section1 div, if you don't need it you can remove it.

Answer (score 1):

look up the .get() and .post() functions in jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/get/

http://api.jquery.com/post/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking to have static content (in this case images) loaded dynamically when users reach the part of the page they exist on.

Take a look at this plugin; I believe it is what you are referring to:

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Good Luck!

Comment: "Lazy Load is currently not usable. It does not work with the latest browsers as expected. I have currently no time updating the code myself."